# How do I view the definition of a function in elm-repl?

Tags: elm

If I type the name of the function in `elm-repl`, I receive the function signature.  I would like to see the actual definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elm-repl` does not provide the source code to functions, but it will show you the function signature as you described.

The [Elm core package page](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/) has a search box where you can type in the name of a function to get an immediate link to the function's documentation, and from there you can get to the source, almost always hosted on Github.